# how to change the text color in javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to change the color of html text if the password is error then it should be shown in red color and if is correct then it should be shown in green color here is the code i am not using jquery i have searched it through the stack flow i found n i tried to implement it but it doesn't worked so i posted this question

```
<div class="td">
    <input type="password" id="txtNewPassword" />
</div>
<div class="td">
    <input type="password" id="txtConfirmPassword" onChange="checkPasswordMatch();" />
</div>
    <div class="registrationFormAlert" id="divCheckPasswordMatch">
</div>
```

and the javascript

```
    function checkPasswordMatch() {
    var password = $("#txtNewPassword").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#txtConfirmPassword").val();

    if (password != confirmPassword)
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords do not match!");
    else
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords match.");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#txtNewPassword, #txtConfirmPassword").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
});
```

i want to change the color of Passwords do not match! to red and passwords match to green

Comment: Use css class or styling

Comment: http://google.it   *jquery change color*

Comment: He is asking for the text color change. You can use `css` method of jQuery as in this http://stackoverflow.com/a/43450050/2737783

Comment: The question has been closed, so this is a comment. I am going to dissent and suggest that you shouldn’t do that in JavaScript. The problem is that when you change your mind about the actual colour or other style, you have to fix that in JavaScript.

You really should do that in CSS. The trick is in two steps.

First define a suitable class in CSS:

`.error { color: red; }`

Next, change the _class_ in JavaScript:

`if (password != confirmPassword) $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").addClass('error');
 else $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").removeClass('error');`

Comment: By the way, this is definitely not efficient coding. Every time you do a test, you run `$("#divCheckPasswordMatch")` again which amounts to a _lot_ of internal code in jQuery. You really should do it once and assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `css` to change the color or

Try this **code**

```js
    function checkPasswordMatch() {
      var password = $("#txtNewPassword").val();
      var confirmPassword = $("#txtConfirmPassword").val();
       if (password != confirmPassword)
       {
        var match="Passwords do not match!";
        var result=match.fontcolor('red');
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html(result);
       }
      else
      {
        var match="Passwords match.";
        var result=match.fontcolor('green');
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html(result);
     }
  }
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#txtNewPassword, #txtConfirmPassword").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="td">
  <input type="password" id="txtNewPassword" />
</div>
<div class="td">
  <input type="password" id="txtConfirmPassword" onChange="checkPasswordMatch();" />
</div>
<div class="registrationFormAlert" id="divCheckPasswordMatch">
</div>
```

Use **Font color attribute** to change the color of text

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to change text color from javascript

```
document.getElementById("divCheckPasswordMatch").style.color = "#ff0000";
document.getElementById("divCheckPasswordMatch").style.color = "magenta";
document.getElementById("divCheckPasswordMatch").style.color = "blue";
document.getElementById("divCheckPasswordMatch").style.color = "lightblue";
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use single line `if` condition and [**`css()`**](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function of jquery

1. if match green color
2. else red color

```js
function checkPasswordMatch() {
  var password = $("#txtNewPassword").val();
  var confirmPassword = $("#txtConfirmPassword").val();
  var html = password != confirmPassword ? "Passwords do not match!" : "Passwords match";
   var color = password != confirmPassword ? "red" : "green";
  $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html(html).css('color',color)
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txtNewPassword, #txtConfirmPassword").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="td">
  <input type="password" id="txtNewPassword" />
</div>
<div class="td">
  <input type="password" id="txtConfirmPassword" onChange="checkPasswordMatch();" />
</div>
<div class="registrationFormAlert" id="divCheckPasswordMatch">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkPasswordMatch() {
    // Other code
    var $message = $("#divCheckPasswordMatch");
    if (password !== confirmPassword)  {
            $message.html("Passwords do not match!");
            $message.css("color", "red");
    } else {
            $message.html("Passwords match.");
            $message.css("color", "green"); 
    }
}
```